# why is subprocess popen giving typeError

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

when i try to do git push using subprocess.Popen

```
        msg, err = subprocess.Popen('git push', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        print msg.stdout.read()
```

i get error saying : TypeError: 'Popen' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating it like an iterable:

```
msg, data = ..
```

This will try to loop over the object and assigning the items to `msg` and `data`. Since the object returned is not an iterable, you have the error.

The [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) constructor returns a `Popen` object. Maybe you want to use `Popen.communicate`? It does return a tuple, `stdoutdata, stderrdata`.

Answer (score 1):

`Popen()` returns not an iterable, but a `Popen` instance.

when you say `a,b = thing`, you assume `thing` is a tuple (or other iterable) which can be mapped to `(a, b)`

Comment: but i m not looping it anywhere

Comment: see my edit, you try to map two values to one object

Comment: `thing` doesn't *have* to be a tuple.  You can even unpack generators (for example) this way.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
msg, err = X
```

will *iterate* over `X` and assign its first element to `msg` and its second element to `err` (and check that `X` has exactly 2 elements).

Since `Popen` instance is not an iterable your code throws "'Popen' object is not iterable".